# java multithreading in android(bluetooth)

Tags: android, multithreading, view, bluetooth

I have a problem ,I m getting data from a bluetooth module and the frequency with which data is coming is very high and i m trying to render those data but the views are not responding with the updated data .Is their possibility   of the side thread which is locking the resource and not allowing the ui thread to change the view﻿.

Comment: give us some code...

Comment: You can always multithread your code the question is whether it'll increase the performance or decrease it. You need to provide detailed inputs with some code.